# Is it possible to have two Bluetooth sockets over one connection on Android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have a client/server Bluetooth connection running between two Android devices. I am sending a lot of data that needs to be read quickly. The reading is happening quick enough but not the writing. The writing thread takes data off a queue and thus items are being put on too quickly for it to keep up. I thought about having multiple sockets (I have a ServerSocket that waits for incoming connections) but when I try to create another client socket I just get this error:

> IO: Unable to start service discovery

Any idea why this is happening or a way around my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The communication speed is limited by the Bluetooth technology and specification, and that link is getting saturated. Opening another socket will not help. Instead, I suggest compressing data before sending, and using some sort of flow control to ensure too much data isn't sent.

Comment: I think you're right and this will probably explain why it is unable to start another connection.  I will try with the compressing, thank you

Comment: @JamesClark compression is only a stopgap measure. You need to look at the queue and the way it works, and stop or control the flood of data at the source for a long-term solution.

Comment: JamesClark and @hexafraction: I think you are talking about bluetooth sockets as in RFCOMM sockets for bluetooth connection between devices. Multiple RFCOMM sockets at a time are always possible in phone(example: Phone handsfree, Phone book transfer) . Service discocery failure can be due to some other reasons

Comment: @ashish Even so, creating more to increase bandwidth isn't going to work.

Comment: @hexafraction :i am not suggesting to create more, my comment was that in android phones, multiple RFCOMM sockets at a time are available and working. If 1 channel is busy transmitting data, BT chip will take care of transmitting data to another channel , error may not be due to multiple RFCOMM socket(based on bt understanding, may be wrong :) )